# What is the purpose of the randomart generated by the ssh-keygen utility?

Tags: security, ssh, ssh-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is randomart produced by ssh-keygen?](https://superuser.com/questions/22535/what-is-randomart-produced-by-ssh-keygen)

Am setting up my git-hub stuff, and part of it entails creating public-private key pair using the ssh-keygen utility. But during this process, there was something describing itself as `The key's randomart`. So what is this about, and how important is it in this ssh key stuff?